# Routing of file-like names in Asp.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is it possible to add a route in the ASP.NET Web API routing configuration that allows handling URLs that look a bit like file names?

I tried adding the following entry in `WebApiConfig.Register()`, but that didn't work (using URI `api/foo/0de7ebfa-3a55-456a-bfb9-b658165df5f8/bar.group.json`):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ContextGroupFile",
  routeTemplate: "api/foo/{id}/{filetag}.group.json",
  defaults: new { controller = "foo", action = "getgroup"}
  );
```

The following did work though (it called `FooController.GetGroup(id,filetag)` as expected) (using URI `api/foo/0de7ebfa-3a55-456a-bfb9-b658165df5f8/group/bar`):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ContextGroupFile",
  routeTemplate: "api/foo/{id}/group/{filetag}",
  defaults: new { controller = "foo", action = "getgroup"}
  );
```

The failed case returns an IIS error (404 - file not found) that looks like it was created by something outside my application. The error page (generated by IIS Express) contained the following error details:

```
Module = IIS Web Core
Notification = MapRequestHandler
Handler = StaticFile
Error Code = 0x80070002
```

I guess that means something called a "StaticFile Handler" got its hands on the request before it reached my code. The big question is: is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 6):

Can you try after having the following settings:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't do the trick. However, your comment pointed me to a useful direction (I hadn't looked at those configuration files). After looking a bit deeper into those I decided that what I was trying to do seems to be going against the design of IIS, and thgough I can probably wrangle it in a way that may make it work, it is probably better to redesign my application (and use request URIs like my second example in the original post)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the handler path filter.
Usualy look like this:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Try with 'path="*"'

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```